# Why does putting $( ... ) or backticks around a command make it return an error?

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a script to upload folder in a bash script. the command is `aws s3 cp $1 s3://$2 --recursive` . However, if I write the command as `$(aws s3 cp $1 s3://$2 --recursive)` or `'aws s3 cp $1 s3://$2 --recursive'`, I would get error `Completed: command not found` and the return code was 127. After I remove that, it runs perfectly. What is the reason of it?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
`aws s3 cp $1 s3://$2 --recursive`
```

Comment: Do not use the backticks. `$(something)` (like its equivalent with obsolete backtick-based syntax) tells the shell to first run `something`, then run *whatever `something` wrote to its stdout* **as another command**. `aws s3 cp` does not write a valid command to its stdout, and when the "Completed" message it writes is run as a command, it fails because `Completed` is not the name of a runnable program you have installed.

Comment: ...serious question: Why did you put the backticks around the `aws s3 cp` command in the first place? I see people do that a lot (because the errors it causes creates questions they ask here and on IRC), and nobody has ever given a comprehensible answer as to why they did it in the first place.

Comment: BTW, your `[[ $? -eq 1 ]]` is testing the exit status **of `echo`**, not the exit status of `aws s3`. You should always immediately store an exit status you want to test later; `something arg1 arg2 ...; something_rc=$?`, and then refer to `$something_rc`, so other commands you run don't unexpectedly change `$?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is *command substitution*; it runs the output of a command as if it were a command itself.

...so, first this is running:

```
aws s3 cp $1 s3://$2 --recursive
```

which emits as output something like `Completing uploading yadda yadda`. So, what do the backticks make this do next? *Run that success message as a command!*

...so, the next command the shell tries to run is something akin to:

```
Completed yadda yadda yadda
```

...which of course fails with:

```
Completed: command not found
```

...because `Completed` is not the name of a program you have installed.

There's no point to using command substitution syntax when you don't actually want to substitute the result of a command somewhere. Don't use syntax you don't understand unless you have a concrete, explainable reason for why you think you need it.